# Crystal Report Formatting and Printing

Tags: c#, wpf, crystal-reports

I am using Crystal Reports to generate an invoice. What I want to do is to print duplicate copies of the small invoice on the same A4 size sheet, one on the top and other on the bottom. I have tried settling with just one copy on the invoice by setting paper size to A3 but it always prints it in Landscape mode, I will be satisfied even if it prints on the top half of the paper only. My client wants to save paper and the invoices are also small. Please suggest me how can I achieve this?

Comment: Voting to close. This is a "code it for me" request, not a question.

Comment: No its not a coding request. I quoted my problem very clearly that when i define page size to A5, it prints in landscape mode, else I would have resolved. Have an attitude to help.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you want to print the same invoice # twice, once on the top half of the paper and once on the bottom half, you could try this:

- design your report such that it will fit in half an A4 page; save it (I'll call it invoice.rpt)
- insert a section details section
- add a subreport to this section (details b), choosing invoice.rpt (inserting a copy of a report into itself)
- link main to subreport on invoice #
- format subreport, check 'Re-import When Opening'; this will ensure that the subreport is always current

If you make changes to the main report, save the changes, then re-open the report--the subreport should have the changes.  You may need to suppress some of the sections in the subreport.

Otherwise, you'll need to do handle this in code.

Comment: Thanks, i am trying this and will post back soon.

Comment: Is there a way to set minimum height of any section? Like if I can set minimum and maximum height of the details section, I can achieve that easily. I am unable to do what you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one as it worked for me.

Go to page setup and set vertical pixel on 5.47 or 5.(as per your requirement) for A4 page . Check image for exact detail.

[image]